# Pandas - find all Rows where special Columns contain a part of text

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I have a problem finding rows of a DataFrame where 2 Columns contain a Part of a given String `s`.

The Column Values (Type String(Object))
I mean about the opposite of `str.contains` or `isin()`, because the substring-mask is the Column-Value.
The String is not suitable for clear splitting, because the 3 Values "Cityname", "Districtname" and "Streetname" can contain Whitespaces.

Can you help me?

```
s = "Bad Testcity Teststr."
df_res = df.loc[(s.find(df['CITY'] != -1) & (s.find(df['DISTRICT'] != -1) & (s.find(df['STREET'] != -1)]`
```

This sample should return TRUE.

```
<bound method DataFrame.info of             ZIP              CITY               STREET NUMBER   NUMBER_SFX         DISTRICT   ONKZ ASB      ADSL      VDSL   VDSL_SV         VPSZ OUTDOOR
ID
4025217   12345  Bad Testcity          Teststr.          6              NaN  Bad Testcity  12345   2  +017.696  +102.784       NaN  49/12345/30       O
4025219   12345  Bad Testcity          Teststr.          7              NaN  Bad Testcity  12345   2  +017.696  +102.784       NaN  49/12345/30       O
4025242   12345  Bad Testcity          Teststr.          8              NaN  Bad Testcity  12345   2  +017.696  +102.784  +185.824  49/12345/30       O
4025244   12345  Bad Testcity          Teststr.         10              NaN  Bad Testcity  12345   2  +017.696  +102.784       NaN  49/12345/30       O
4025245   12345  Bad Testcity          Teststr.         11              NaN  Bad Testcity  12345   2  +017.696  +051.392       NaN  49/12345/30       O
...         ...              ...                   ...        ...              ...              ...    ...  ..       ...       ...       ...          ...     ...

[1569530 rows x 13 columns]>
```

Comment: how does your dataframe look like?

Comment: and what is your text exactly that you want to look up in the columns?

Comment: Typically I create a new boolean column with the logic that you want and then filter. If you then don't want that column you can drop it.

Comment: I've edited the "look up"-String and posted the DF structure.

Comment: @Chinny84: 
Ok, but  the problem is still the same. How do i have to formulate the conditions for this logic?

Comment: df_res = df[df.apply(lambda row: s in row['CITY'] and s in row['DISTRICT'], axis=1)]
you need to modify the lambda function inside the apply method. In this modified line, we're checking if the substring s is present in both the CITY and DISTRICT columns for each row in the DataFrame. Adjust this line according to your requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
           ZIP          CITY    STREET  NUMBER  NUMBER_SFX      DISTRICT   ONKZ  ASB    ADSL     VDSL  VDSL_SV         VPSZ OUTDOOR
ID                                                                                                                                 
4025217  12345  Bad Testcity  Teststr.       6         NaN  Bad Testcity  12345    2  17.696  102.784      NaN  49/12345/30       O
4025219  12345  Bad Testcity  Teststr.       7         NaN  Bad Testcity  12345    2  17.696  102.784      NaN  49/12345/30       O
4025242  12345  Bad Testcity  Teststr.       8         NaN  Bad Testcity  12345    2  17.696  102.784  185.824  49/12345/30       O
4025244  12345  Bad Testcity  Teststr.      10         NaN  Bad Testcity  12345    2  17.696  102.784      NaN  49/12345/30       O
4025245  12345  Bad Testcity  Teststr.      11         NaN  Bad Testcity  12345    2  17.696   51.392      NaN  49/12345/30       O
```

You can concatenate the columns with a space, then use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) on the output:

```
s = "Bad Testcity Teststr."

df_res = df.loc[(df['CITY']+' '+df['DISTRICT']+' '+df['STREET']).str.contains(s)]
```

Less efficient alternative (can nevertheless be useful):

```
df_res = df.loc[df[['CITY', 'DISTRICT', 'STREET']]
                .apply(' '.join, axis=1)
                .str.contains(s)]
```

Output (here unchanged):

```
           ZIP          CITY    STREET  NUMBER  NUMBER_SFX      DISTRICT   ONKZ  ASB    ADSL     VDSL  VDSL_SV         VPSZ OUTDOOR
ID                                                                                                                                 
4025217  12345  Bad Testcity  Teststr.       6         NaN  Bad Testcity  12345    2  17.696  102.784      NaN  49/12345/30       O
4025219  12345  Bad Testcity  Teststr.       7         NaN  Bad Testcity  12345    2  17.696  102.784      NaN  49/12345/30       O
4025242  12345  Bad Testcity  Teststr.       8         NaN  Bad Testcity  12345    2  17.696  102.784  185.824  49/12345/30       O
4025244  12345  Bad Testcity  Teststr.      10         NaN  Bad Testcity  12345    2  17.696  102.784      NaN  49/12345/30       O
4025245  12345  Bad Testcity  Teststr.      11         NaN  Bad Testcity  12345    2  17.696   51.392      NaN  49/12345/30       O
```